# ANTLR Program stops reading an input file

Tags: antlr, antlr3

i have a problem with this grammar:

```
//parser    
macchinaTuring: { init();}
           listaIstruzioni 
           {env.insertwarning();
           }
    ;

    listaIstruzioni : (istruzioni)+ 
    ;

    istruzioni : (LP statoiniziale VI statofinale VI DIR RP PV (commento)? CAPO)
    ;

    statoiniziale:s=STATE VI c=CHAR 
            {env.insertstatoiniziale($s, $c);} 
    ;

    statofinale: x=STATE VI y=CHAR
            {env.insertstatofinale($x, $y);}
    ;

    commento : BAR STRING
    ;

    // lexer

    LP    : '(' ; 
    RP    : ')' ;
    VI    : ',' ;
    PV    : ';' ;
    DIR   : ( '='           
          | '<'
          | '>' 
          ) 
       ; 
    BAR   : '//' ;
    CAPO  : (('\r' '\n') | ('\n') | ('\r'));
    CHAR  : (('a'..'z')|('A'..'Z')) ;
    STATE : ('0'..'9')+ ;
    STRING: (('a'..'z')|('A'..'Z')|('0'..'9')|' ')* ;
    ERROR : . ;
```

I've made a test class which analyzes an input file in which every line is a sentence of `istruzioni`. If the LP character is missing, the program doesn't recognize the new line and it stops reading. How to solve? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The start rule needs to end with an explicit `EOF`, which tells ANTLR to continue reading to the end of the file.

```
macchinaTuring
: { init();}
  listaIstruzioni
  EOF // <-- add this
  {env.insertwarning();}
;
```

Comment: I've already tried this and other solutions with EOF, but it doesn't work. If there's not LP at the beginning of the line I receive this error:
`line 3:0 missing EOF at '1'`
where 3 is the number of the line without LP

Comment: ANTLR 4 uses an improved error recovery mechanism in this specific case known as "Jim Idle's magic sync" error recovery. If you want this feature in ANTLR 3, you'll need to implement it yourself throughout the grammar (documentation of this feature for ANTLR 3 is sparse at best, you're basically on your own). The ANTLR 4 implementation is mentioned in Chapter 9 of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference.

Comment: It's really the only way to solve this problem? I'm not expert using ANTLR, but with other similar grammars I never had this kind of troubles.